# Any way to automatically handle precompiled headers in visual studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, precompiled-headers

I have a solution in Visual Studio 2015 that includes multiple related C++ projects, static libraries that are built then linked into a single executable. Here's a simplified diagram of the solution:

`+ Solution
   + Project 1 (static library)
     - Header1.h (included by all other files in Project 1)
     - File1.cpp
     - File2.cpp
     - File3.cpp
   + Project 2 (static library)
     - Header2.h (included by all other files in Project 2)
     - File4.cpp
     - File5.cpp
     - File6.cpp
   + Project 3 (executable)
     - (contents not relevant to this example)`

I want to make the compiler use precompiled headers, so that if either `Header1.h` or `Header2.h` (or any of their dependencies) changes, those changes only need to be compiled once, not three times (once for each .cpp file in the project).

At first I tried setting each project up to compile all .cpp files with /Yc to create the precompiled headers (which I assumed would only actually create them once). This works well in debug mode, but bafflingly, gives warning messages in release mode. (I can understand it not being allowed, but why would it work in debug mode but not in release mode?)

So far, the easiest way I've found to get this working is to set each project to compile .cpp files with /Yu, which makes each file *use* precompiled headers, and then override the settings for one file in each project to compile with /Yc, to *create* the precompiled headers. Visual Studio seems to realize what I'm doing and compiles the file with /Yc first, then the others.

Shouldn't there be an easier way to do this? Can't Visual Studio figure out automatically "If multiple files are set to use the same precompiled header, pick one file to create it", or "If multiple files are set to create the same precompiled header, only one creates it" like it seems to do in debug mode automatically?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: That's just how precompiled headers work. If you create a new project (other than the "Empty Project" type), two of the files created are stdafx.h (the precompiled header) and stdafx.cpp (the one file set to /Yc). Why do you need different behavior?

Comment: Because I don't want "stdafx" files cluttering up my project, and because it seems really cludgy to do it this way.